# Converting 2 ASCII char values into short int

Tags: c, char, short

I need to converto two ascii `char` value into one `short int`. This is my function:

```
void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
        int i;
        char* auxchar = pchar;
        short* auxshort = pshort;

        for(i = 0; i < KEYSIZE/2; i++)
        {
        *auxshort = (auxchar[0] << 8) | auxchar[1];
        auxshort++;
        auxchar += 2;
        }
}
```

However, when I go and print out the values, I often get a bunch of FFFF in the beggining. Copypasted from my terminal:

```
    FFFFFFF7    FFFFFC24
    3049    3E1B
    FFFFFFE3    5705
    FFFFFFBC    FFFFA960
    FFFFFFB1    FFFFFF84
    FFFFFFEB    FFFFFFAD
    FFFFFFDA    FFFFFFCC
    FFFFFFB8    FFFFFFB0
    FFFFFFC7    1125
```

And this is the orignal number I'm trying to convert:

```
  static unsigned char keychar[]={
            0x8C,0xF7,0xFC,0x24,0x30,0x49,0x3E,0x1B,0x6D,0xE3,0x57,0x05,
            0x67,0xBC,0xA9,0x60,0x58,0xB1,0xBD,0x84,0xDD,0xEB,0xE8,0xAD,
            0x69,0xDA,0x49,0xCC,0x49,0xB8,0x5D,0xB0,0x42,0xC7,0x11,0x25}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Try casting your chars to unsigned chars before shifting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow then! As a new user, you may want to read the [Introductory Tour To Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief overview of the site.

Comment: It sounds like you might be outputting the values wrongly too (e.g. using `%x` for `short`); `short` is typically 16-bit value but your output is displaying 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

All narrow data types are promoted to `int` before arithmetic. The way you are doing this wrong in many places.

- First your data are `unsigned char` but in the function you have them as `char`.
- Probably `char` is signed on your machine so you get negative values where there weren't before.
- These negative values get sign expande to `int` and you store them into `short`,
  instead of `unsigned short`.

Get your types right, and this will work.

Comment: Might want to adding note about printing `short`.

Comment: @chux, in that case I merely think that he should have all types unsigned, so `%x` is the right format here.

Answer (score 1):

The code is unnecessarily complex and fails to properly handle sign extension and  fails to allow for promotion to `int` in the calculations.

Suggest:

```
// call this function for each pair of char by:
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(keychar); i+=2)
{
    char2short( &keychar[i], &myshort );
    //  process myshort
}

void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
    short result = 0;

    if( ('0' <= pchar[0]) && ('9' >= pchar[0]) )
    { 
        result +=  pchar[0]- '0'; 
    } // end if

    if( ('0' <= pchar[1]) && ('9' >= pchar[1]) )
    { 
        result *= 10;
        result +=  pchar[0 - '0'; 
    } // end if

    *pshort = result;
} // end function: char2short
```

Your question was not clear, perhaps you want to take each successive 2 `char` and stuff them into a `short` then

```
void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
    char result[2] = {'0','0'};

    result |= pchar[0];
    result <<= 8;
    result |= pchar[1];

    *pshort = (short)result;
} // end function: char2short
```

--or even simpler --

```
void char2short(char* pchar, short* pshort)
{
    *pshort = *(short*)pchar;
} // end function: char2short
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to

```
 for(i = 0; i < KEYSIZE/2; i++)
    auxshort[i] = (keychar[i*2] << 8) | keychar[i*2+1];
```

`char` type is, depending n the compiler, either `signed` or `unsigned`. If it is `signed`, the all bytes between 0x80 to 0xFF are considered negative numbers and when converted to `int` by the default int promotion rule, their value will be 0xFFFFFF80 to 0xFFFFFFFF (32 bit int). Therefore you have to convert them to unsigned value before they are promoted to integer. Your `keychar` array is declared as `unsigned char` so nothing is really necessary to be added to your code.
On modern compilers and processors, pointer arithmetic is generally not faster than array indexing but is more difficult to read, so avoid it for trivial code.